# Hogwarts Motto from J.K. Rowling's "Harry Potter" series

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation, motto, passive-voice

Hogwarts, the School of Witchcraft and Wizardry in the *Harry Potter* books, has the following Latin motto: *Draco dormiens numquam titillandus*.

Most online sources translate this as "Never tickle a sleeping dragon". However, it occurred to me that, since *titillandus* is a future passive participle, it should not necessarily be translated as the main verb. Additionally, *draco* and *dormiens* are both masculine, so I don't think they should be translated as the nominative subject.

I have come up with a couple of potential translations:

> A sleeping dragon never to be tickled.

This does not flow very well in English however, so I was thinking that perhaps *est* was omitted from the motto. On the basis that *est* should have been included, *titillandus est* would then be a passive periphrastic. As a result, we could then say

> A sleeping dragon is never to be tickled.

or

> A sleeping dragon must never be tickled.

Though "never tickle a sleeping dragon" still preserves the meaning, I believe that the other translations I propose are more accurate with respect to the Latin.

I would like to know if anyone can think of other potential translations that I am missing. Furthermore, can the active equivalents of intended passive phrases as such be considered equally legitimate? Are there any other historical or modern examples of this?

Comment: Your translation is exactly what I thought the first time I read the motto, and I can't help thinking the book's is but a _free_ translation.

Comment: Well spotted.  Isn't the supine used for negative commands? *Numquam titillatum est* +Accusative.

Comment: The translation is syntactically free, but many translations are to some extent. As long as it preserves the meaning (which it does) it seems unobjectionable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right that it's a gerundive of obligation, and thus requires a form of *esse*. However, it doesn't have to be expressed. Tacitus *Annals* 1.29 contains two without *esse*, though they're in indirect statements:

> certatum inde sententiis, cum alii opperiendos legatos atque interim comitate permulcendum militem censerent, alii fortioribus remediis agendum: nihil in vulgo modicum; terrere ni paveant, ubi pertimuerint inpune contemni: dum superstitio urgeat, adiciendos ex duce metus sublatis seditionis auctoribus. promptum ad asperiora ingenium Druso erat: vocatos Vibulenum et Percennium interfici iubet. tradunt plerique intra tabernaculum ducis obrutos, alii corpora extra vallum abiecta ostentui.

This [commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=RmboCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120) agrees with this position.

Answer (score 6):

One could also read the entire motto as a description of the school:
maybe Hogwarts is "a sleeping dragon which should not be tickled".
I am not familiar enough with the school to tell if this is a sensible interpretation, but it strikes me as a reasonable option.
In this reading the motto is not an instruction for students but a description of the school.

I asked [a separate question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2193/79) about such uses of gerundive to make sure that this interpretation is indeed grammatical.