# ante solem occasum vs. *ante diem adventum

Tags: verbs, syntax, deponent-verbs, ablative-absolute, dominant-participle

The intransitive verbs that typically enter into constructions with perfect participles of the so-called ["**dominant**"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/how-obligatory-is-the-predicate-in-a-dominant-participle-construction) type are **deponent**: e.g., *ante Ciceronem mortuum*, *post Ciceronem natum*, etc. The same generalization holds for Ablative Absolute constructions like *Cicerone mortuo*, *Cicerone nato*, etc. However, some ***non***-deponent intransitive verbs can also be found in these constructions: e.g., *ante solem occasum*, *sole occaso*, etc.

> Tum facito **ante solem occasum** ut venias advorsum mihi (Pl. *Men.* 437)

> Quibus verbis ita videtur dierum observationem divisisse, ut qui **post solem occasum** ante mediam noctem natus sit, is ei dies natalis sit, a quo die ea nox coeperit (Aul. Gell. *Noct. Att.* 3.2.3)

> quae horis sublata duabus // omnia sunt **sole occaso** (Lucil. *Sat.* 68-69).

Putting transitive verbs aside (e.g., cf. *post urbem conditam*, *Barcinone condita*, etc.), I was wondering which is the specific grammatical class of *intransitive* verbs that can enter into these participial constructions. Or to put it simply: why is it the case that a non-deponent intransitive verb like *occidere* can enter into an Ablative Absolute (*sole occaso*) and into a dominant (perfect) participle construction (*ante solem occasum*), but an equally non-deponent intransitive verb like *advenire* can't? E.g, cf. the ill-formedness of *die advento* and *ante diem adventum*.

NB:  As for Romance languages it seems to be the case that those intransitive verbs that can typically enter into absolute participle constructions are the so-called [**"unaccusative**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb) ones: e.g., Cat./Sp. *morir* 'to die' in Cat. *Mort Ciceró*,.../ Sp. *Muerto Cicerón*, ...; Cat. *arribar* / Sp. *llegar* 'to come' in Cat. *Arribat el dia*..., / Sp. *Llegado el día*,..., etc. However, Latin appears to make a different cut since unaccusative verbs like *advenire* (e.g., *ubi dies advenit* (Sall. *Jug.* 113)) cannot form, as pointed out above, Ablative Absolute constructions like **die advento* nor other dominant (perfect) participle constructions like **ante/post diem adventum*.

Comment: *Sol occasus* is a very special case. To my knowledge, *sol* is the only word in the whole Latin language that can be used with *occasus* like that. You cannot say *post Pompeium occasum*. Perfect participles with an active sense *do* exist, like *cenatus, pransus, adultus, obsoletus, inveteratus, …* but I do not think dominant-participle constructions have anything to do with it.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree with you that _ante solem occasum_ and _sole occaso_ are “very special cases” but these examples are attested and their existence/usage must then be accounted for (in contrast, I take invented examples like _advento die_ or _ante diem adventum_ not just as “very special” or “very peripheral” but directly as ill-formed; but cf. TKR’s comment. Given that they also violate the typical rule, only their being attested could lead me to reconsider my non-native judgement).

Comment: Cases like _sole occaso_ and _ante solem occasum_ are "very special" but they do exist, so there must be some _motivation_ for their existence: e.g., an **analogy** with “regular”/expected cases like _sole orto_ and _ante solem ortum_, the ones involving a deponent verb. Similar (attested!) examples of "very special cases" are welcome! For example, I remember I got surprised to see that a non-deponent verb like _erumpere_ (?) also appeared in an Ablative Absolute in a context related to a vulcano (crucially, the intransitive use of the verb was involved) but I can't remember the source...

Comment: Eo and sto are classic intransitive verbs. So what do itus and status actually mean?

Comment: @fdb I'm not sure what you mean. For example, are you asking what the participle could mean in an (adapted) example like _Sic itum est ad astra_?

Comment: If non-deponent intransitive verbs cannot form a perfect passive participle, what is itus and what is status?

Comment: @fdb The fact that a nominative form like _itus_ cannot be used in any syntactic context and the fact that that an impersonal passive like _itum est_ is also referred to as "pseudopassive" are related. This said, it's fine to use the traditional grammatical label (perfect passive participle) for them. The occasional quotation marks on "passive" are just used to call attention on facts like the abovementioned ones.