# Translation of Fratres Occasi

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

Someone in my organization is trying to sell memorial challenge coins with the text "Fratres Occasi", which they claim means "Fallen Brothers".

This seems, not right to me. My Latin is not excellent, so I though I would ask the group here what you make if this.

Answer (score 9):

You are right, *fratres occasi* is not correct. *Occasus, -a, -um* is indeed the perfect passive participle of [*occidere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Doccido2) (with a short i), and this verb does indeed mean “to fall,” usually not in the literal sense, but in the sense “to perish, to be lost.”

However, since it is an intransitive verb, it forms no personal passive. *Fratres occasi* would mean “brothers that have been fallen,” and that makes no sense. The **only** exception to my knowledge is if the subject is *sol*, as in *post solem occasum* (after sunset), etc. But never mind that. Quod licet soli, non licet fratri.

But *occidere* has a doppelgänger, [*occīdere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Doccido1) (with a long i), which means “to strike down, kill, slay.” It *is* transitive (unsurprisingly) and *does* form a personal passive, but the perfect participle is *occīsum*. So you could say: *fratres occisi*.

Comment: You're right that *sol* is the exception, not the rule. Whoops.

Comment: The perfect ("passive") participle _occasus_ seems to be lexicalized only in a "dominant participle" construction, perhaps by **analogy** with the **deponent** verb _orior_: e.g. cf. the expected _post solem **ortum**_ with the unexpected _post solem occasum_. So, rather than saying, as above, "However, since it is an intransitive verb, it forms no personal passive", here I'd say: "Since it is **not** a **deponent** intransitive verb, it is not expected to form a perfect ("passive") participle". Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12529/ante-solem-occasum-vs-ante-diem-adventum

Comment: @cmw Your deleted statement is, linguistically speaking, very interesting (although it is wrong): “there's nothing wrong with _fratres occasi_ meaning ‘fallen brothers’”.  I find it VERY interesting since it shows that unaccusativity in Latin is not to be “equated” with unaccusativity in English and Romance languages (NB: interestingly, ‘fallen brothers’ is perfect in these languages but _fratres occasi_ is out in Latin).  So your statement seems to be motivated by a nice transposition of L1 (English) to L2 (Latin). That’s why I said that it is very interesting from a linguistic point of view.

Comment: @Mitomino It's not entirely alien to the Latin mindset, but it's odd enough that it warranted comment. The Twelve Tables (V?/IV?/III? s. BCE) and Lucilius (II s. BCE) both have *sol occasus* meaning "setting sun", but that prompted questioning from Aulus Gellius (II s. CE). Because of the similarity with *occasus, -us*, it's difficult to pin down exactly the number of times it was used in this way, but it seems this is a singular usage. It's the only way *occaso* is used, for example, and there are no instances of *occasorum* or *occasis*.

Comment: @Mitomino But indeed, I had a linguistic lapse for a second. It actually caught me off guard, as I'm usually more careful than that! I'll chalk it up to a distraction and hope it doesn't recur.

Comment: @cmw  Well, perhaps, as you say, it was a (mere) "distraction", but, as noted above, I thought that it was due to a L1-to-L2 transfer, which is, linguistically speaking, more interesting. Yes, _sol occasus_ is a nice example of a dominant participle construction in subject position, which is, by the way, not a frequent position for this kind of participles. Finally, since, as pointed out by Sebastian, this participle is only applied to _sol_, it is not surprising that "there are no instances of _occasorum_ or _occasis_".

Comment: @Mitomino It indeed was a L1-toL2 transfer. What's more interesting is subjective, but as this is not the Linguistics stack, I was trying to keep it more on topic with Latin. What I find interesting is that there's an exception at all. Whence comes it?

Comment: @cmw You're right, "what's more interesting is subjective" but what I was just trying to say is that the transfer "is, linguistically speaking, more interesting" _than a mere distraction_ (sorry, I omitted this part in italics!). As for the issue that concerns us here, the existence of the participle _occasus_ is not unrelated to the lexical-semantic fact that the verb _occido_ also expresses a **change of state** _like_ the deponent verb _orior_. Otherwise, the participle _occasus_ would be impossible. See above for a "like"(analogy)-proposal. Construction Grammarians love these quirks!

Comment: @Mitomino I was fully expecting you to comment ;-) My wording was not very precise, to be sure. (Glaringly obvious example: One might write *fratres mortui*.) Veniam mihi dari posse spero. If I had written that these verbs are not expected to form passive participles at all, a pedant might have asked what about *huc ut perventum est* etc. …

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Let me say I wouldn't think it is "pedantic" to comment on the fact that an intr. verb like _pervenio_ can enter into an impersonal passive but, probably (I'd say "interestingly"), the same cannot be said of the apparently similar intr. verb _occido_, the verb at issue (!) here. I'm aware I can often be regarded as a pedant. Sad but, given your comment, probably true... BTW: if I were you, I'd add a translation/gloss of _fratres occisi_ at the end of your answer. In the context of the question above, an inattentive reader could interpret/translate this example incorrectly.

Comment: @Mitomino It was not at all my intention to accuse you of pedantry. Your comments are always welcome, if on occasion perhaps a bit above my pay grade. I do think, by the way, that an impersonal passive like *postquam ad Cannas occasum est* would be possible, although unusual and perhaps not attested. But why not?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel  An important condition for an impersonal passive to be possible is that the verb must be agentive. That's why _occasum est_ would be unusual and, as you say, "perhaps not attested". Probably, a similar semantic restriction is found in German.

Comment: @Mitomino that is a good question that I've never thought much about. The German Wikipedia happily claims that unaccusative intransitive verbs form no impersonal passive, and their first example is that "Dann wurde eingeschlafen" (Latin equivalent would be *tum obdormitum est*) is ungrammatical. I wonder how many speakers agree with that; I certainly don't. Another obvious counterexample is "Gestorben wird immer" (people will always die), title of countless books. So who knows ...

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Yes, you'll also find this typical restriction not only in Wikipedia but also in the linguistic literature (e.g. cf. the unergative/agentive ex. (1b) and the unnaccusative/non-agentive ex. (2b) on page 317 of https://web.stanford.edu/~azaenen/publications/unaccusativesindutch.pdf ). However, when the verb "fall" is construed as agentive, the sentence is said to sound better (e.g. see ex. (41) on page 329 of this pdf).

Comment: So, _mutatis mutandis_, one could entertain the hypothesis that _pugnatum est_ is perfect but _occasum est_, if possible, would sound as somewhat unnatural unless construed as agentive.  As far as I can tell, this hypothesis is borne out in Latin impersonal passives (e.g. _pugnatum est_ and _perventum est_ sound perfect because they contain agentive predicates).

Comment: @Mitomino: What does "they contain agentive predicates" mean--they are amenable to an agent e.g. "pugnatum est a militibus" = "it has been fought by the soldiers". Is that correct?

Comment: @tony Yes, _pugnare_ is a prototypical example of agentive verbal predicate (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)), whereby an impersonal passive construction like _pugnatum est_ is very natural. In contrast, the intr. verb _occidere_ does not involve an **agent** (i.e. **a participant who carries out an action deliberately or with volition/control**), whereby I don't think that an impersonal passive like _occasum est_ would sound natural (the reason is given in the comment that contains this link: https://web.stanford.edu/~azaenen/publications/unaccusativesindutch.pdf ).

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: If "fratres occasi" is translated as simple (aorist) past, as opposed to, perfect passive, then it's "brothers (who have) fallen" e.g. "amatus sum" = "I have been loved"; simple-past = "I was loved". Do you agree?

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you. In the light of this analysis how does, "occasum est a gladio" = "one (impersonal pronoun) has been killed by the sword", work? I suppose, as you say, this does not sound very natural.

Comment: @tony if you wanted to translate it as active, which, as I wrote, would be wrong, then the "fallen brothers" would seem fine, but it depends on context. It might also be a dominant participle. You usually don't translate *post solem occasum* as "behind the set sun," but as "after sunset."

Comment: @tony The instrumental ablative of your example should not be preceded by a preposition (cf. the ablative of agent _a militibus_ in your previous comment vs. the instrumental ablative _gladio_). Note also that your example contains the (non-relevant) verb _occīdere_ (with a long i; cf. Sebastian's answer), which means 'to kill'. The relevant verb that is at issue here is the **intransitive** _occidere_ (with a short i), which means "to fall, to die". So note the difference between _occisum_ and _occasum_.

Answer (score 3):

In virtually all Indo-European languages, ancient or modern, there is a rule that states that the perfect participle of transitive verbs is passive in meaning, but the p.p. of intransitive verbs is active. E.g. in Sanskrit sthā- means “to stand”, but sthita- means “having stood”, in exactly the same way that English says “departed friends”, from the intransitive verb “to depart”, or “fallen soldiers” from the intransitive verb “to fall”.  In Latin, however,  this use of the p.p. is mostly restricted to intransitive deponent verbs. What is surprising is not that Latin can say “post solem occasum” but rather that it cannot use this inherited IE construction with other intransitive verbs. Essentially what has happened is that this construction is no longer productive in Latin and has survived only in the fossilised “post solem occasum”.

Comment: From your parallelism between Sanskrit and English it is not clear to me if you consider the role of unaccusativity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb). The participial construction exemplified by _{fallen/departed} soldiers_ is only typical of a subtype of intransitive verbs (unaccusative ones like _{to fall/to depart}_) but not of the so-called unergative ones like e.g. _to fight/to work_ (cf. _{*fought/*worked} soldiers_). Is this difference based on so-called "split intransitivity" relevant to Sanskrit as well? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: @Mitomino. I am not sure that I understand your objection. I have approached the problem from a morphological standpoint. sthā- / sthi-ta- is morphologically the exact equivalent of sto / sta-tus. But their usage diverges.

Comment: I was wondering if your "other intransitive verbs" (cf. "What is surprising is not that Latin can say _post solem occasum_ but rather that it cannot use this inherited IE construction with other intransitive verbs") coincide with the set of (some) unaccusatives, unergatives being disallowed (_*post Caesarem pugnatum_). From what you say ("Essentially what has happened is that this construction is no longer productive in Latin"), it seems natural to infer that other (unaccusative?) verbs besides _occidere_ could enter into this construction before the fossilization of _post solem occasum_.

Comment: My take is quite different: _post solem occasum_ is indeed an unexpected (or “surprising”, to put in your terms) pattern since only deponent intransitive verbs would be allowed to enter into it. Since _occido_ is not a deponent verb, my hunch is that the quirk _post solem occasum_ could only have been idiosincratically created by analogy with _post solem ortum_ on the basis of their related encyclopedic meaning (sunset and sunrise) and their shared structural lexical-semantic meaning as well (both _orior_ and _occido_ are change of state verbs).