# Can "titillo" refer to the literal action of tickling?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

My question was inspired by the phrase in [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/hogwarts-motto-from-j-k-rowlings-harry-potter-series):

> draco dormiens numquam titillandus

...where *titillo* presumably refers to the action of "tickling."

Is this use of *titillo* attested? [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtitillo) gives that as one of the English definitions, but all of the examples I can find correspond to the figurative English meaning of "tickle," i.e. "titillate."

I cannot find [a single classical example](http://latin.packhum.org/search) where this word is used to describe the literal action, which leads me to doubt whether the above phrase would have provoked a strange reaction in a Roman.

**Is there any justification for the use of *titillo* outside of its figurative sense of "titillate"?**

Comment: The verb seems to be quite rare. I found [14 hits](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=titill*), and Seneca seems to be the most likely source of physical tickling. I couldn't find online English translations of Seneca to help deciphering the passages. For example,  [opposing *titillare* to *vulnerare*](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1014/1/1/18209-18215@1#1) might fit the bill, or perhaps [*titillatio corporis*](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1017/15/91/2602-2608@1#91).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is there any justification for the use of titillo outside of its figurative sense of "titillate"?**

Yes, I think so.  See Pliny the Elder, *Natural History*, book XI, 77:198

> *in eadem praecipua hilaritatis sedes, quod **titillatu** maxime
>   intellegitur alarum ad quas subit, non aliubi tenuiore humana cute
>   ideoque scabendi dulcedine ibi proxima.*
>
> In it [the diaphragm] also is the chief seat of merriment, a fact that is gathered
>   chiefly from **tickling** the arm-pits to which it rises, as nowhere else
>   is the human skin thinner, and consequently the pleasure of scratching
>   is closest there.

Answer (score 4):

So, I learned something new about English today. I began to jump on your question from an etymological angle, pointing out the origin of *to tickle* when, to my surprise, I discovered the original meaning of *tickle* was physical, at least according to [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tickle).

However, if you look at the development, you'll see a figurative use "tickle" used to translate the Latin "titillare" from the 14th century.

> Meaning "to excite agreeably" (late 14c.) is a translation of Latin titillare. Meaning "to poke or touch so as to excite laughter" is from early 15c.; figurative sense of "to excite, amuse" is attested from 1680s. To tickle (one's) fancy is from 1640s.

This is the meaning I thought Rowling meant her Latin to mean, and if I were to see the English today, I would not automatically assume it meant put their fingers to its underbelly, but sort of "excite/arouse," since the consequences are dire even if the dragon is "agreeable."

Comment: Interesting: so the "titillate" sense of English "tickle" was added afterwards by analogy to Latin *titillare*? In which case, the answer to my question is that *titillare* cannot in fact refer to the physical action of "tickling"? As for Rowling, *non flocci facio*--it just inspired the thought :)

Comment: @brianpck There might be confluence. Look at Penelope's recent answer. I'd say that the physical action is the extended meaning, though.

Answer (score 1):

Smith's gives examples, both figurative and physical:

titillo, -avi, -atum I *v.a. to tickle, titillate* : sensus, Lucr. 2, 429 ; Cic. Fin. I, II 39 ; carnem Tert. Pud. 22 *med*. : multitudinis levitatem voluptate quasi titillantes Cic. Off. 2, 18, 63  **ll** Fig. : ne vos titillet Gloria Hor. S. 2, 3, 179 : femina nulla prorsus invidia titillata, Mart. Cap. 2, 42.

titillus, i, m., [titillo] *a tickling* : Cod. Theod. 8, 5, 2.

[Rowling uses her bits of "Latin" purely for effect — really, I think, hardly intended as more than nonce-words or expressions. I don't feel that we can expect to get much of an insight from it into anything very serious, can we?]

Comment: Could you specify which of these examples are not figurative?

Comment: To be clear: I see that it's divided into two numerals, but the first division seems to exclude uses that I am not interested in. By "literal" I meant "the physical action of tickling."

Comment: Not sure I understand your second comment. Otherwise, I think that _carnem_ and _med_ might be clues. And what does Cicero mean by _quasi titillantes_ if not something physical?

Comment: Cicero: "as if tickling (?) with pleasure the shallowness of the multitude" Tertullian: "subduing the tickled (?) flesh" Neither fits the bill.

Comment: Then we shall have to leave it at that, because I can't follow you.

Comment: "Physical action of tickling": I really don't know how much further I can clarify. "The mother tickled her child" NOT: "This tickled my fancy."

Comment: Well, one last try. [btw  The Latin Library version has _titillantium_, not _titillantes_ Smith's error, not mine, I think]. Cicero surely is suggesting that the multitude is being amused as if they were being physically tickled? And that really is all I have to say. You can lead a horse to water . . . . !